# firestore rules posted - still receiving emails from google

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, rules

I have received an email from Google about not having implemented rules for a database. Checked - had generally `read&write` open. Changed to `read&write` only for authorized users. Created a user with `pwd` but received another email from Google about not having implemented the rules... Can someone tell me what could be done with this?

My current Firebase Rules:

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service cloud.firestore { 
    match /databases/{database}/documents { 
        match /{document=**} { 
            allow read, write: if (request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 4, 19)) && (request.auth.uid != null); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your rules..?

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          (request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 4, 19)) && (request.auth.uid != null);
    }
  }
}

Comment: @kern1986 please add the rules as an edit to your question so that they can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

If the emails arrived closely or if the second email arrived close to you changing the Firebase Rules might mean that google has not detected that you changed your Firebase Rules or that this information was not yet replicated into all their systems before the trigger to send a new email to you was activated.

So I would say you could simply ignore that email as your rules are allowing authenticated users only, which is enough for be considered secure for an initial state.

Comment: thank you,yes seams so,no more complaints from google

Comment: @kern1986 in that case consider accepting/upvoting the answer